# Will the dealer removing some minor paint marks/drips on the side of a car hurt?

Tags: paint, paint-clearcoat

I recently bought a new car from a dealer, the car has a few quite small dots that look like yellow road paint but didn't come off with the normal detailing they do. The dealer noticed it before I left the lot and wants to have his body shop team fix it. Curious if this should be a concern that the repair/fix will weaken the integrity of the factory paint job or if it is safe to trust the dealer?

I am assuming they will just take a super light abrasive to hit the spots or something that probably won't even affect the clear coat, but I don't know much about car paint and don't want a problem later because of it...

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The good news is the dealer is willing to fix it correctly. If they are having the body shop team work on it, then it will be dealt with by professionals who know what they are doing to repair the finish of the vehicle.

To answer your question, there really isn't any way for us to know with what little detail you have provided. Most likely it is stuck to the clear coat and will be easily repaired. Even if it takes more extensive paint repair, that is what body shops do.

Comment: They just used a little body shop thinner on a cloth and it came right off. Followed by a wash to get any left over thinner off. Guessing it is just a diluted version of paint or lacquer thinner.

Comment: Great to hear it was a simple resolution. Enjoy your new car.